# Subtract Aggregate and Non-aggregate in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm learning calculated formula in tableau and tried to work out a simple calculation:

Column values: Scores of a student in a test

Tried out : [student score] - AVG[student score] which i want to find for each student record .

and understood that tableau does not allow aggregate & non-aggregate to be mixed.
came across LOD functions also but those didnt seem of use here.

How to work on this error and what is the calculation happening in the background by tableau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
SUM([student score]) - SUM({AVG([student score])})
```

- The first element provides the individual student's score.
- The second is an LOD which takes the average of all student scores across the dataset.

  - The LOD itself is non-aggregate so it requires an aggregating function (SUM in this case)
  - The LOD can be customized to operate in many ways. This is merely the simplest example.

As a matter of learning, I might also suggest splitting the LOD function into its own calculated field. This will allow for you to add it to the view separately, fine tune it, and see how changes affect the overall calculation. In this case the calculated fields would look like this:

1. [LOD AVG] calculated field = 
   {AVG([student score])}
2. [SUM - AVG] calculated field = SUM([student score] - SUM([LOD AVG])

Alternatively, you can look into 'Table Calculations' which were the predecessors to LODs.